# Meteor public assets are not working

Tags: meteor

I put an image file called x.png inside `/public` folder.
I try to access it through

`<img src='/public/x.png>` but the image doesn't show up. So I go to the url `/public/x.png` to check if it shows up, but all I see is a blank page with no errors both on client and server. I am really stuck. Does anyone know why this is happening? I also tried putting `x.txt` inside `/public` and accessing it via `/public/x.txt`, but all I see is a blank page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**/public** is not part of the image URL, you can access to your image throught :

```
<img src='/x.png>
```

https://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/specialdirectories

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the URL of the image. If the image file is directly under `public` directory of Meteor, you can access it as

```
<img src="x.png">
```

If the image is in some other directory within `public` say `public/something/img.jpeg` then you can access it as

```
<img src="something/img.jpeg"
```